# Get image location using a drag and drop

Tags: vb.net, image

I have a drag and drop event to get images into a picture box.  I need to get the image location to string to store on my database.  I can get the location if I use a OpenFileDialog, but if I use a drag and drop, I can't seem to get it.  Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub picCategoryImage_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles picCategoryImage.DragEnter


    'Procedure to copy the dragged picture from the
    'open window

    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then

        'If the file explorer is open, copy the picture to the box
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        picCategoryImage.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        TextBox1.Text = picCategoryImage.ImageLocation

    Else

        'otherwise, don't take action
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        btnDeleteImage.Visible = False

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub picCategoryImage_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles picCategoryImage.DragDrop

    'Procedure to select the pictue and drag to picturebox
    Dim picbox As PictureBox = CType(sender, PictureBox)
    Dim files() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())

    If files.Length <> 0 Then

        Try

            picbox.Image = Image.FromFile(files(0))
            btnDeleteImage.Visible = True
            picbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            picCategoryImage.BringToFront()
            btnDeleteImage.BringToFront()


        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Image did not load")

        End Try

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `files(0)` (in the drop event) is the file name,  maybe call a procedure at the end passing it as an arg to be saved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Plutonix, you're already using the file path so you've already got it.  That's how `Image.FromFile` is able to create an `Image` from a file.  If you mean that you need to be able to get the path later then you have two main choices:

1. Do as you're doing and store the path in a member variable for later use.
2. Instead of calling `Image.FromFile` and setting the `Image` of the `PictureBox`, just call the `Load` method of the `PictureBox`.  You can then get the path from the `ImageLocation` property.

I would actually suggest using option 2 regardless, because it has the added advantage of not locking the file the way your current code does.